# Why does my Rspec post :create invalid parameter controller test fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have two tests for my controllers.

```
spec/controllers/employees_controller_spec.rb

  it 'should create a new valid employee' do
    employee_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:employee)
    expect { post :create, employee: employee_params }.to change(Employee, :count).by(1)
    should redirect_to(action: :index)
  end



  it 'should not save an employee with an invalid avatar extention' do
    invalid_employee_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:employee)
    invalid_employee_params[:avatar] = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/photos/duck.txt')))
    expect { post :create, employee: invalid_employee_params }.to_not change(Employee, :count).by(1)
  end
```

When I execute these tests, the first test passes while the second one fails. Here is the error below:

```
Failure/Error: expect { post :create, employee: invalid_employee_params }.to_not change(Employee, :count).by(1)

 NotImplementedError:
   `expect { }.not_to change { }.by()` is not supported
 # ./spec/controllers/employees_controller_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have followed Rspec's documentation found here [Rspec doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-2/docs/matchers/expect-change)and it seems correct to me. This looks like a simple error to fix but  I'm not quite sure what is going on. Could someone help point out my error. I am new to Rspec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well looking at the error, it looks like you cant use the `by` matcher for testing `to_not change`. intuitively, you should just be expecting it to not change the count. you shouldnt be testing that its **not** changing **by** 1, because that test would pass if the count changed by 0 or 2, which i imagine would lead to many false positives

does this work?

```
expect { post :create, employee: invalid_employee_params }.to_not change(Employee, :count)
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil for the help! I didn't think about the false positive scenario either.