# Rails - Rspec: test PUT update to actually change Model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following:

```
let(:update_request) { put "/api/v3/account/profile.json", attributes, credentials }

describe "PUT 'update'" do
  before { update_request }

  context "updating normal attributes (no password)" do
    let(:attributes) {
      {
        profile: { first_name: 'John', phone: '02 21231321', email: 'aieie@brazorf.com' }
      }
    }

    it do
      aggregate_failures do
        # expect{response}.to change{current_user.reload.email}.to('aieie@brazorf.com')
        expect(response).to be_success
        expect(current_user.reload.first_name).to eq('John')
        expect(current_user.reload.phone).to eq('02 21231321')
        expect(current_user.reload.email).to eq('aieie@brazorf.com')
      end
    end
  end
...
```

The expectation that in the code above is commented out fails with the following message:

> Failure/Error: expect{response}.to change{current_user.reload.email}.to('aieie@brazorf.com')
>          expected result to have changed to "aieie@brazorf.com", but did not change

How can I test that a call to a controller PUT/update action actually change the Model attributes?

**edit**

If I inspect and evaluate `current_user` with binding.pry before and after the failing test, I see it actually changes. The test still fails tho

```
binding.pry
expect{response}.to change{current_user.reload.email}.to('aieie@brazorf.com')
binding.pry
```

Comment: may be *validation* failed?

Comment: another thing I noticed here is that, post request should be inside the block like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41730044/2767755 .

Comment: nope, last test pass

Comment: ok I see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reload your object before expectations:

```
current_user.reload
expect(current_user.email).to eq('new@ya.com')
```

Or another way:

```
it do
  expect do
    subject
    user.reload
  end.to change(user, :email).from('test@ya.com').to('new@ya.com')
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You have change your expectation code like below to make use of **change, from and to**,

```
expect {
  put "/api/v3/account/profile.json", attributes, credentials
}.to change{current_user.reload.email}.to('aieie@brazorf.com')
```

Actually it's good to place **request statements(GET, PUT, POST and DELETE)** inside the **it block**, so that we should be able to make use rspec expec features.

Comment: I got the same `expected result to have changed to "aieie@brazorf.com", but did not change` failure